Apache Flink Kafka source properties.group.id to Kafka consumer group
I created a Flink table with Kafaka source like the following:
CREATE TABLE click_event_source (
  cnt_id STRING,
  cnt_type STRING,
  ua STRING,
  en STRING,
  event_time TIMESTAMP_LTZ(6)
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'bdp.ub',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '<server addresses>',
  'properties.group.id' = 'flink_bdp_test',
  'format' = 'json',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
  'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
  'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',
  'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true'
);

It seems like the property properties.group.id should be the Kafka consumer group name. But when I use the command
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <server address> --list

to list all the consumer groups I could not find the group flink_bdp_test listed as one of the consumer groups.
But the table is indeed getting messages from Kafka.
Any help to clarify the meaning of properties.group.id?
Thanks

Please confirm whether you have enabled CommitOffsets On Checkpoints

Kafka source commits the current consuming offset when checkpoints are
completed, for ensuring the consistency between Flink’s checkpoint
state and committed offsets on Kafka brokers.
If checkpointing is not enabled, Kafka source relies on Kafka
consumer’s internal automatic periodic offset committing logic,
configured by enable.auto.commit and auto.commit.interval.ms in the
properties of Kafka consumer.

-- from: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#consumer-offset-committing
